# Is "halt … so recht" some kind of idiom?

Tags: idiom

Simple question here. Below is an example sentence from a Ger2Ger dictionary:

In meinem Alter wollen die Augen **halt nicht mehr so recht**.

My question is the phrase "halt...so recht" some kind of idiom? I think what the sentence says is something like "my eyes don't see so good anymore in my old age" but I can't be sure.

I can't seem to parse this sentence precisely with other dictionaries. Other examples sentences using this structure would be extremely appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

> My question is the phrase "halt...so recht" some kind of idiom?

No, it isn't.

First of all ***halt*** used in that sentence doesn't have anything to do with the verb ***halten*** as you implied in your question title.

It's an adverb used to indicate an ongoing/normal process in that sentence.

A correct translation to english would be the word ***just*** for example:

> > At my age the eyes **just** don't work that well anymore.

---

Other usage examples

- > > Das ist halt ein grosses Haus.
  > >
  > > ---
  > >
  > > It is just a big house.
- > > Das war halt schon immer so.
  > >
  > > ---
  > >
  > > It always was just like that.

Comment: More accurately, *halt* is a modal particle. Unlike other adverbs, it cannot be first in a sentence (*Halt wollen meine Augen nicht mehr so recht" doesn't work)

Comment: But I think "*nicht* ... so recht" is an idiom. Or isn't it?

Comment: @Rudy If so, then the idiom is _"nicht so recht wollen"_.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: or "*nicht so recht können*", "*nicht so recht wissen*", etc. So I think the idiom is simply "*nicht so recht ...*".

Comment: @Rudy I'm just not  sure that much, if it's really an idiom. I also just don't know that much. :3